# Atualizar uma aplicação Access

Tags: sql-server, aplicação-web, vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-office

Qual a forma mais fácil de fazer o upgrade de uma aplicação Access desktop com VBA para uma aplicação web com sql server?

Comment: Qual é a versão do Access? // Conhece SQL Server?

Comment: Access 2016. Conheço SQL mas não sou administrador das máquinas, ou seja, tenho restrições de acessos.

Comment: Espero que o SSMA for Access funcione com a versão 2016 do Access. Na documentação consta somente até Access 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel, há duas linhas de atualização, que me parecem parcialmente paralelas: a migração de sgbd (Access para SQL Server) e a substituição de linguagem/ambiente.

---

**BANCO DE DADOS**

Para migrar o banco de dados do Access para o SQL Server você pode utilizar o "Assistente de Migração do Microsoft SQL Server" (SSMA, no original em inglês). Detalhes em [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant). Há vasta documentação sobre a variação específica para Access e recomendo atenção na leitura dela, em especial na parte de compatibilidade.

Outra alternativa é realizar *access upsizing*, que é o processo de migrar alguns ou todos os objetos de banco de dados de um banco de dados do Access para um banco de dados do SQL Server novo ou existente. Está disponível na guia `Ferramentas de banco de dados`, no grupo `Mover dados`, item `SQL Server`. Observe que a localização pode variar de acordo com a versão do Access. Instruções completas em 
[Mover dados do Access para um banco de dados do SQL Server usando o Assistente de Upsizing](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mover-dados-do-Access-para-um-banco-de-dados-do-SQL-Server-usando-o-Assistente-de-Upsizing-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924).

---

**APLICAÇÃO**

Na web há vários artigos sobre [migrar aplicação access to web](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&q=migrate%20vba%20access%20application%20to%20web). Teve a oportunidade de estudar algum deles?